# How to convert Numpy array to Polars dataframe with multiple outputs

Tags: python, lambda, python-polars

I made a feature request outlining something similar ([multiple column output](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13895)), but I want to be specific about my use-case. I am doing a kmeans analysis and I want to just get the numpy arrays back, but they keep getting parsed as objects. I tried doing `tolist()` in the dataframe but it just loads for a long time. I want to do this on multiple images so I can see this slowing down.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import polars as pl
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


def kmeans_img(filepath: str, n_clusters: int):
    image = plt.imread(filepath)
    X = image.reshape(-1, 3)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    segmented_image = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_].reshape(image.shape)

    return (
        image,
        segmented_image,
    )
```

Imagine we had an [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Viceroy_Butterfly.jpg) of a butterfly, where we save the path as `butterfly_filepath`. The rest proceeds as follows:

```py
butterfly_df = pl.DataFrame({"filepath": butterfly_filepath})


out = (
    butterfly_df.with_columns(
        results=pl.col("filepath").map_elements(lambda x: kmeans_img(x, 3))
    )
    .with_columns(
        og_img=pl.col("results").list.get(1),
        seg_img=pl.col("results").list.get(1),
    )
    .drop("results")
)
```

When I run this code, I get this error: `polars.exceptions.ComputeError: ValueError: cannot parse numpy data type dtype('O') into Polars data type`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75713598/numpy-array-to-list-of-lists-in-polars-dataframe) touches on the casting issue here, but I am not sure how to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return multiple items, use a Python `dict` (which corresponds to a [Polars Struct](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/structs/#combining-group-by-operations)).

- `tolist()` involves copying data, use `pl.Series` instead.

```py
return dict(
    og  = pl.Series(X),
    seg = pl.Series(segmented_image)
)
```

```py
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ filepath              ┆ results                           │
│ ---                   ┆ ---                               │
│ str                   ┆ struct[2]                         │
╞═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ Viceroy_Butterfly.jpg ┆ {[[86, 103, 61], [87, 102, 61], … │
└───────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

```py
Elapsed time: 7.04423 seconds
```

- the `tolist()` approach was ~3x longer (25 seconds)

You can then [`.unnest()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) the struct column.

> ```py
> (df.with_columns(results = pl.col("filepath").map_elements(lambda x: kmeans_img(x, 3)))
>    .unnest("results")
> )
> ```
>
> ```py
> shape: (1, 3)
> ┌───────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
> │ filepath              ┆ og                                ┆ seg                               │
> │ ---                   ┆ ---                               ┆ ---                               │
> │ str                   ┆ list[list[u8]]                    ┆ list[list[f64]]                   │
> ╞═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
> │ Viceroy_Butterfly.jpg ┆ [[86, 103, 61], [87, 102, 61], …… ┆ [[120.626352, 123.41985, 59.6664… │
> └───────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
> ```

### Struct vs. List

Another important point is that a Polars `list` has a **single** type.

If we look at the result of your `.map_elements` call before any further processing:

```py
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ filepath              ┆ results                           │
│ ---                   ┆ ---                               │
│ str                   ┆ list[list[list[i64]]]             │ # <- int
╞═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ Viceroy_Butterfly.jpg ┆ [[[86, 103, 61], [87, 102, 61], … │
└───────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

The orignal types are lost:

```py
X.dtype # uint8
segmented_image.dtype # float64
```

This is not the case inside a `struct` - it can contain values of different type.

Comment: Thank you. I like the added benefit of preserving the types. And yes you are right this was so slow and I didn't know why! Polars is so cool I am going to continue to explore the docs.

Comment: @jquirious how would I go about ranking the pixels in this image in the segmented image? I am trying to get the top 5-10 colors used in an image, so I will adjust the k parameter and run this on about 200 images. So this structure will remain the same where we have lists of lists.

Comment: @AdrianFletcher I'm not sure I follow what that involves exactly - counting the occurrences of each `[x, y, z]` sublist?

Comment: @jquirious Yes exactly that. Since each row will be an image, I will need to have those counts returned in a struct so that it doesn't shape of the original dataset.

Comment: Probably worth creating a new question for that. Sounds like it may involve `.top_k()` or perhaps `.value_counts()` on the lists.

Comment: I got something working, so I will make another question to address its verbosity

Answer (score 0):

While playing around with the code a bit more, I was able to get the result I wanted by adding `.tolist()` in the return statement. I reshaped it since I want to do further analysis on the pixels themselves not the shape of the OG image:

```py
def kmeans_img(filepath: str, n_clusters: int):
    image = plt.imread(filepath)
    X = image.reshape(-1, 3)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    segmented_image = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_].reshape(-1, 3)


    return (
        X.tolist(), # change made here - I can just use X
        segmented_image.tolist(), # change made here - I can just reshape the segmented image beforehand
    )
```

This runs a bit slow, so if anyone has any faster implementations of this, that would be greatly appreciated.