# How to gather the top k elements from a nested list of lists in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

This is a follow-up to a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77860634/8646265) question. I have a dataset that has two columns: a list of [R, G, B] values for an image and that same list once I run it through the K-means algorithm. I want to count the top n values and I got this code that explodes the list and calls a bunch of functions to give me my answer. I am just wondering if there's a more streamlined/cleaner way to do this. I need everything to return to a single row because I will have multiple images to process and I can't start reshaping the dataset.

## Output

```py
shape: (1, 3)
┌───────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ filepath              ┆ og                                ┆ seg                               │
│ ---                   ┆ ---                               ┆ ---                               │
│ str                   ┆ list[list[u8]]                    ┆ list[list[f64]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ Viceroy_Butterfly.jpg ┆ [[86, 103, 61], [87, 102, 61], …… ┆ [[120.626352, 123.41985, 59.6664… │
└───────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

## Code

```py
out.select(pl.col.og.explode()).group_by(pl.col.og).len().top_k(
    by=pl.col.len, k=10
).to_struct("result").struct.field("og").implode()
```

```py
shape: (1,)
og
list[list[u8]]
[[0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0], … [201, 233, 150]]
```

Comment: Hmm yeah, looks like `.top_k()` is not implemented for lists. It probably makes sense to actually do this inside the `kmeans_img` function? e.g. `pl.Series(X).value_counts(sort=True).head()` (perhaps a new question was a bad suggestion on my part - apologies.)

Comment: This bit `.to_struct("result").struct.field("og").implode()` can just be `[”og"].implode()` is that the final result you're going for and you just want it cleaner or are you trying to get all the columns back? It's not clear, at least to me.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I was actually running into the issue - I do want the columns back, so I think jquirious' comment about the underlying structure is what should apply here. I do just want the top 10 columns, so if I can do that before that's actually easier for my use case.

Comment: @jqurious it's much faster to run your code after the columns are created. I think it might have to do with the fact there's a parallel argument in the value_counts function that I set to true.

Comment: I came back to this and will post a quick solution I came up with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer references `Polars 0.20.6`:

```py
import polars as pl

# Example DataFrame with a column of lists
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "values": [
            [
                [1, 2, 3],
                [1, 1, 3],
                [2, 2, 3],
                [2, 2, 3],
                [1, 2, 3],
                [1, 2, 3],
                [1, 2, 3],
                [1, 2, 3],
            ],
        ]
    }
)

# Group by the new column and count occurrences
out = (
    df.explode("values")
    .group_by("values")
    .agg(count=pl.len())
    .sort(pl.col.count, descending=True)
)
print(out)
```

## Output

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬───────┐
│ values    ┆ count │
│ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ list[i64] ┆ u32   │
╞═══════════╪═══════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 5     │
│ [2, 2, 3] ┆ 2     │
│ [1, 1, 3] ┆ 1     │
└───────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Now, the *seg* column is completely left out and not only the top *k* elements are returned. Is that the desired result?

Comment: Yes. The actual project uses the seg column cause it buckets the colors with the kmeans algorithm. I'll create a color palette based on the top 10 most frequent colors. This will be a struct column for each row (so imagine imploding the values and count in a struct using implode). That part I know how to do so I didn't include to keep the question focused. I am sure people have other use cases, but if they need to preserve columns they can wrap all this in a `with_column` statement.

Comment: @Hericks so to clarify, that exact result that I have showcased here is part of what I want.